# orientation change

Tags: iphone

I need to show fade-in kind of transition effects while the view changes its orientation from one mode to other. Can anyone suggest me how to get that?

Answer (score 1):

I would use an animation block inside of this method like so:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"InterfaceFade" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];

    // Change properties to animate here (Ex: view.alpha = 0.0)

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: the fading works, but still I can see the window rotating prioir to it. I there a way not to get that? And many thanks for your respone.